# What is the Asymptotic Order of the Sum of Random Variables with non-finite Moments?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $X_i$ is independently and identically distributed over $i$, and $E(|X_i|^d)$ with $d>0$ is not finite or undefined:

- I am wondering whether $\sum_{i=1}^N |X_i|^d$ is of any asymptotic order. Take [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Mean) as an example. If $d=1$, then $N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is still Cauchy and hence
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^N |X_i|\ \mbox{is}\ o_p(N^{1+\delta})\ \mbox{for any}\ \delta>0
  $$
  That is $N^{-(1+\delta)}\sum_{i=1}^N |X_i|$ converges in probability to $0$.
- If $d=2$, $E(|X_i|^2)$ is infinite. I am not sure whether there exists $\delta>0$ such that
  $N^{-(1+\delta)}\sum_{i=1}^N |X_i|^2$ converges in probability to
  $0$.
- Another interesting example is related to [Central Limit Theorem (CLT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT): if $X_i$ follows [student t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Moments) with $3$ degrees of freedom independently over $i$, then $E(X_i)=0$, $E(X_i^2)=3$ and any moments of order higher than 3 do not exist. Due to CLT, $N^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ converge in distribution to $N(0,3)$. Hence, $(N^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)^3\leq 3!N^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{i=1}\sum_{m=1}\sum_{j=0}X_iX_{i+m}X_{i+m+j}+N^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i^3=O_p(1)$. Since the third moment of normal distribution with zero mean is $0$, one could conjecture $E[(N^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)^3]$ tends to $0$ (notation abuse due to the non-existence of $E(X_i^3)$). One should have $N^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i^3=o_p(1)$ or $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i^3=o_p(N^{\frac{3}{2}})$. Similarly, $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i^d=o_p(N^{\frac{d}{2}})$ with $d\geq3$ if the sequence $\lbrace X_i\rbrace$ satisfies the CLT conditions, though such asymptotic orders may not be on the boundary.

Comment: For the Cauchy distribution with $d=2$, I have found [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25050525), which shows $\sum X_i^2=O_p(N^2)$. In general, this seems to be a hard problem. Define $G_{d}(x)=1-P_d(x)$, where $P_d(x)$ is the cumulative distribution funtion of $|X_i|^d$ and $G_{d,N}(x)$ is the counterpart for $\sum |X_i|^d$. The answer could be related to the order of $G^{-1}_{d,N}(c)/G^{-1}_{d}(c)$ for some constant $c$ close to $1$.